# Differentiate between web part page and wiki page with Powershell - CSOM in Office365 Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, wiki-pages, web-part-page

I am working on a power shell script with CSOM to copy/export all the web parts from one source page and import them to another target page in the site pages library In Office 365 site.

I am using following command to get the object of current target/source page.

```
$Page = $ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($PageURL)
```

Now the object returned with this method does not support any property or method that shows whether current page is a web part page or wiki page.
If the page is a wiki page then and then only we need to add webpart zone and then add webparts to them.

**Web part pages** as we know have predefined layouts with webpart zones already added.. so we can add the copied web part within webpartzones with webpartzone id like "Left Column" using following command

```
$pageWPManager.AddWebPart($webpartdef,$WebPartZoneID,$WebPartZoneIndex)
```

where

**$WebPartZoneID can be "Left Column", "Body" etc.**

**$WebPartZoneIndex can be index like 0,1,2,etc.**

But in case of **wiki page** we need to pass either

```
$WebPartZoneID = ""
```

or we can first add a webpart zone in wiki page and then add the webpart there.

But since i am looping on all pages of the library, i first need to decide whether current page is wiki page or webpart page..

Is there a way to do this with Powershell and CSOM for an O365 or SP Online page?

Any help would be appreciated..